# PHPDoc - Documenting @param's without the param in the function?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm currently building up some phpdoc for a restful API - and I took to using the `@param` doc syntax for notating required params over POST.

However, after generating the phpdoc, I noticed that it refuses to list these parameters unless they match exactly with input variables into the method itself.

`@uses` and `@see` don't look good nor make much sense here when it comes to the phpdoc output. The style/look of the doc is perfect with the `@param` functionality.

Is there any way to override the rules put in place by PHPDoc, and allow it to generate `@param` blocks in the documentation, even if the param doesn't exist in the method itself?

Comment: What about `@var`?

Comment: unfortunately still not much good - this dumps the var information into the sidebar ala uses/sees, and neglects to note the type/var name. I'm looking to have the param outlined in the exact same way that a standard @param docline would be.

Comment: PHPDoc isn't really suited for end-user docs. Take a look at API Blueprint or Swagger.

Comment: @AlexHowansky understandable - but if there were a way to override PHPDoc from checking if the param existed in the method, then it'd work exactly as intended. The doc isn't for public consumption - it's for internal use. The model files are already working through PHPDoc, so for ease of use/centralization, I'm trying to get the API working through it too. All I need to do is find a way to disable PHPDoc from checking if the param I'm noting is in the function.

Comment: You're mixing concerns here. And long story short - no, phpDoc won't allow to alter any of its behavior. You can try with HTML table though in the method's header.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to document your API, I suggest you use proper tools like [API Blueprint](http://apiblueprint.org) or [Open API Spec](https://www.openapis.org).

And by using [Swagger](http://swagger.io), you can even use [annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) (which is what you apparently want) to document the API and in turn, generate the documentation out of it.

Just don't use PHPdoc for it, because that's just mixing concepts altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I'm going to answer this with the solution I've found - I appreciate all the "do not do that" answers, but still hope that someone who finds themselves in a similar situation to myself ala "this needs to be done immediately without changing the format, and we cannot allot any time to this" will find it useful in the future.

You can maintain using the @param syntax if you initialise the method with the param specified, and simply set it to null - ensuring it doesn't break any existing calls.

```
/**
* Remove a group
*
* @param int $pricing_group_id Required
* @return mixed JSON array with remaining groups
*/
public function remove($pricing_group = null) {
    ....
}
```

Your PHPDoc output will now show the param type, name, and description as normal.

Keep in mind that this is not good practice - nor is it even remotely correct practice. But it'll work until you can convince a higher-up to allot you enough time to rebuild the existing documentation on a more suitable platform.

Comment: Sorry, but is just **terrible** advice. If upper management doesn't want to spend resources for documentation/tests/whatever, that's fine, but don't leave these types of solutions, stating that _it's upper management's fault, so I'll do it like this_. You can just omit the `@param` part altogether and document whatever you want inside the PHPdoc section `/** */`.

Comment: @QuetzyGarcia this solution does not output anything through phpdoc, which was the entire point of the exercise. And unfortunately, in the working world, you're constantly forced to rely on shitty solutions like this - with the only alternative solution being to recompile phpdoc to force it to recognise `@param` tags for output, when no params exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilizing "optional". IE:

`@param string $variable (optional) Blah.`

See other examples at https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html .

This is to be used in the use case of when a parameter is optional, unlimited parameters, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference - tried with both (optional), and OPTIONAL as noted on the doc page listed above.

Comment: That manual goes with phpDocumentor 1.x, so it's not still valid for 2.x (complete rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a "custom" tag, maybe `@parameter`, so that it is listed "as is".  You won't get the same hyperlink behavior for class names as the param tag provides, but you won't be limited by the lack of parameters in the code signature itself.  Maybe use an inline link tag in the parameter description that points to the class type of the parameter.  Otherwise, the uses, see, or link regular tags can be on separate lines as convenient links to the classes that are your parameter types.

There is currently no way to disable the internal behavior of "actual code signature overrides param tags" logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the same approach for documenting virtual methods as a workaround, i.e. via a [`@method`](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html) entry in the phpDoc header for the class.

E.g.:

```
/**
 * ... 
 *
 * @method mixed remove(integer $pricing_group_id) Remove a group and return a JSON array with remaining groups.
 */
class YourClass {

   ...

   // see class header for phpdoc entry
    public function remove($pricing_group = null) {
        ....
    }

}
```

A downside is that (to my knowledge) this approach does not provide a means to enter explicit description entries for the method's parameters and return value.